# Wiring a chandelier gone wrong

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I installed a new chandelier for a friend and I am used to basic wiring( ground/ white/ black) when wiring new light fixtures. This light was hooked to one switch and a dimmer across the room. When I pulled the old lighting off the ceiling it had an extra wire (red). The new chandelier only has ground white and black wires so I capped the red and connected the other corresponding wires and closed up the light. I turned the power back on from the breaker and checked the light and it was on and each switch and dimmer didn't cut the circuit like it should have. What am I supposed to do with this red wire to make this light work as it should?

Comment: Did you take a picture of how it was wired up before to the old chandelier? Can you add a photo of what's up there right now?

Comment: I’m betting it’s a switch loop and the always-hot is wired to the light. The red is probably the switched hot.

Comment: if you are not a licensed electrician, then it is possible that what you are doing is illegal in your area